# How to use pm2 to run grunt serve

Tags: node.js, deployment, gruntjs, pm2

my colleague passed me a project that you run grunt serve to start. Now I'm trying to use pm2 to start the project in the background forever so I can close my command line. However, I couldn't find a right way to do it.

I've seen answers like

cd /path/to/fullstack

pm2 start grunt --name website -- serve

but I don't quite understand and I have very little knowledge regarding grunt. All I know is that grunt serve runs multiple tasks at the same time for me.

I know that if I know the base js file that creates a web server for my app such as index.js. I can just run pm2 start index.js.

I tried to run the base file with node index.js, but it gives me an error cuz I need to run babel at the same time which is done by the grunt serve.

Can anyone help me to run grunt serve command using pm2?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to create a [ecosystem file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) and put these configs :

`script: 'grunt'` and `scriptArgs: ['serve']`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to achieve this in 2019, here's the solution. Leverage PM2 and [PM2's Ecosystem File](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/).

First, create a file named `ecosystem.config.js`.

Then, do something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : 'myapp', // the name of your app
    cwd    : '/path/to/myapp', // the directory from which your app will be launched
    script : '/usr/local/bin/grunt', // the location of grunt on your system
    args   : 'serve' // the grunt command
  }]
};
```

Then, just run:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```